# Why does this code return a view result with no ViewName?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have some code inside a controller called AdminController.

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    AdminModel model = new AdminModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

When I inspect the view in a test method...

```
 var result = controller.Login();

 //assert
 Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
 Assert.AreEqual("Login", ((ViewResult)result).ViewName);
```

It doesn't show a view name. However the Login view is definitely returned. I'm wondering why no view name is set? I thought it defaulted to the action result method name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewName is only set if you set the `viewName` parameter when your return the view.  For example:

```
return View("Login", model);
```

Otherwise, if no view name is set it uses the default view.

Therefore, to test for the default view your assert should be written:

```
Assert.AreEqual("", ((ViewResult)result).ViewName);
```